# Unity Surface Shader - Runtime UV mapping

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, shader, procedural-generation, uv-mapping

I want to map a 2D Texture onto a procedurally generated plane, using vertex local position, in Unity. This is the code:

```
Shader "Custom/planeTest"
{
Properties
{
    _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Scale("Scale of texture", Vector) = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    _Offset("Offset of texture", Vector) = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
}

SubShader
{
    CGPROGRAM

    #pragma surface surf Standard vertex:vert
    #pragma target 3.0

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    float3 _Scale;
    float3 _Offset;

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
    };

    void vert(inout appdata_full v, out Input o)
    {
        UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input, o);
        o.uv_MainTex = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xz;
    }

    void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
    {
        float2 _uv = (IN.uv_MainTex.x * _Scale.x, IN.uv_MainTex.y * _Scale.y) + _Offset.xy;
        o.Albedo = tex2D(_MainTex, _uv).rgb;
    }

    ENDCG
}

Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

I don't understand why, but this makes the plane's color uniform.
The only option I can use is **_Offset**, that changes the color of the entire plane. I think **(IN.uv_MainTex.x * _Scale.x, IN.uv_MainTex.y * _Scale.y)** it's always zero, but I don't understand why.

Please help me understanding what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I think you meant to say `float2 _uv = float2(IN.uv_MainTex.x ...`. You can also write componentwise  multiplication like `float2 _uv = IN.uv_MainTex*_Scale.xy +_Offset.xy`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it!

Answer (score 0):

Check https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaders.html under "**Surface Shader input structure**"

**uv_MainTex** is automatically generated, so setting it manually might create some problems. You might want to use another custom name in your input struct.

Side note: you should do all your arithmetic in the vertex shader, since they are all linear transformations anyway.